# Customize lineplot marker size based on values of a column

Tags: python, seaborn, line-plot

I have a data like the following:

```
 #df
  df = pd.DataFrame({
               'id': {0: -3, 1: 2, 2: -3, 3: 1},
               'val': {0: 0.4, 1: 0.03, 2: 0.88, 3: 1.3},
               'indicator': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
               'count': {0: 40000, 1: 5779, 2: 3000, 3: 31090}
              })
df
```

if I do the following code, I will have:

```
 sns.relplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', size = 'count', data = df)
```

[image]

I want to have a line connecting the dots. But if I change the plot to a line plot, I will have any graphs.

```
sns.lineplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', size = 'count', data = df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you want to combine a `lineplot` with a `scatterplot`

```
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', data = df)
sns.scatterplot(x = 'id', y = 'val', hue = 'indicator', size = 'count', data = df)
```

[image]